# Redirecting to detail page in Streaming API

Tags: javascript, jquery, streaming-api

I was just trying to get heads-up on Streaming API. Following is the link which provides a basic example for [Streaming API](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API). I'm using the same code, besides that i was trying to add one functionality i.e. redirecting users to detail page. Once i get the ID from the streaming API i want to provide a link to detail page. I tried but unable to crack it. I'm not a pro in jquery, javascript. Any suggestions will be helpful.

This is block of code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($)
{
        $(document).ready(function() {
        // Connect to the CometD endpoint
        $.cometd.init({
            url: window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname+'/comet/24.0/',
                requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth {!$Api.Session_ID}'}
        });
        // Subscribe to a topic. JSON-encoded update will be returned
        // in the callback
        $.cometd.subscribe('/topic/EmailUpdates', function(message) {
        var $recordId = JSON.stringify(message.data.sobject.Id);
        alert('1' + message.data.sobject.URL__c);
        $('#content').append('<p><a href="javascript:void(0);return false;" onclick="redirectURL(JSON.stringify(message.data.sobject.Id));return false;">'+JSON.stringify(message.data.sobject.Subject__c) + '</a></p>');
       });
       });
       })(jQuery)

       // Tried with writing a function and calling this on click of a tag or  apex:outputLink
       function redirectURL(link)
       {
          alert('hi');
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

An sObject detail page will have a URL with the format:

> https://**instance**.salesforce.com/**recordId**

E.g. A lead detail page on the na5 server.

> https://na5.salesforce.com/00Q700000000H50

So you will want something like the following in your JavaScript to redirect to the detail page.

```
window.location.href = '/' + JSON.stringify(message.data.sobject.Id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Actually i tried this too before i didn't work....if i tried to add this on <a> tag href then it wont work...I tried using apex:outputLink and then called a Js function onClick of but somehow its not working saw "FireBug" also no clues.

Comment: Got a workaround for this...Created a formula field URL__c with HYPERLINK('../../../' & Id , Subject__c , '_new')....And in page instead of  

$('#content').append('<p><a href="javascript:void(0);return false;" onclick="redirectURL(JSON.stringify(message.data.sobject.Id));return false;">'+JSON.stringify(message.data.sobject.Subject__c) + '</a></p>');

used this 

$('#content').append('<p>' + message.data.sobject.URL__c + '</p>');